# spring data JPA common @EnableJpaRepositories for multiple projects - shared jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-autoconfiguration

i'm using spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE and spring-data-2.2.5.RELEASE

we have multiple projects in different git repositories and I'm trying to create a common JSON repository to work with MySQL JSON functions via shared jar.

i created the following in my common jar which has an autoconfiguration

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface JsonRepository <T>{

    int appendToArray(T entity, String arrayPath, Object item, String storeId) throws JsonProcessingException;

    int removeFromArrayByValue(T entity, String arrayPath, String feild, String value, String storeId);
}
```

configuration class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = JsonRepositoryImpl.class,
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = JsonRepositoryFactoryBean.class
)
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig {

}
```

and i have a `spring.factorie` files in my resources which configures this as autoconfiguration

and my implementation repository

```
@Repository
public interface SettingsRepository extends JsonRepository<Settings>, CrudRepository<Settings, Long> {
}
```

**the problem**

when i consume my common jar which include all json commons i made, spring-data stopes detecting all repositories and i can't start the application because of missing beans

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'XXXService' defined in file [XXXService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.XXXRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
```

it only works if i add another @configuration in the consuming project, and i want to make it work automatically to save defining it on every project i want to add JSON query capabilities

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        repositoryBaseClass = JsonRepositoryImpl.class,
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = JsonRepositoryFactoryBean.class,
        basePackages = "xxx.*"
)
public class CoreConfig {
}
```

how i can fix it ??

Comment: Try to make `JsonRepository <T>` extend `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository` in order to make Spring implicitly autogenerate implementation for it.

Comment: i don't need an implementation for JsonRepository, is it just a composite interface

Comment: Then you loose SpringData "magic" that generates repository implementation. Error message clearly states it: `No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.XXXRepository'`

Comment: i want spring to generate an implementation for a repository that extends JsonRepository, and not for JsonRepository itself, for example SettingsRepository.